# Validate schema and data

Tags: javascript, json, types

For an exercise I need to validate some data with a schema. I could validate the first level (`id, name, value`), checked if it's required or not, and that the type asked matched but I couldn't find a way for the nested one `parents`, do you know how it's possible?

```
function validate(data, schema){...}

const data = { 
  cards: [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Paris",
    value: 99,
    parents: [{
      id: 8,
      name: "Parent 1",
      value: 200, 
      parents: [] 
     }]
 }] 
}

const schema = [{ 
   name: 'id',
   required: true,
   type: 'number'
 }, { 
  name: 'name',
  required: true,
  type: 'string'
 }, { 
  name: 'value', 
  required: true,
  type: 'number' 
}, { 
  name: 'parents',
  required: false, 
  type: 'array:card' 
}]
```

I'm stuck for the type `array:card`, where I'm supposed to check if what's within parents is similar to the root of the object. If possible without doing a for within a for because technically this object can be nested to infinity.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Recursion feels like it was born for this kind of problem. This demo uses slightly simplified validation criteria.

```js
// Recursively applies a validation function to each card
const {cards} = getData();
for(const card of cards){
  validate(card);
}

// Defines the validation function
function validate(node){

  // Does something conditionally based on whether node passes tests
  const valid =
    typeof node.id == 'number' &&
    typeof node.name == 'string' &&
    typeof node.value == 'number' &&
    Array.isArray(node.parents);  
  if(valid){ console.log(`node ${node.id} looks good`); }
  else{      console.error(`node ${node.id} is invalid`); }

  // If possible, moves down a level to validate more nodes
  if(node.parents?.length){
    for(const parent of node.parents){
      validate(parent); // Recursive call
    }
  }
}

// Gets the initial data
function getData(){
  return { 
    cards: [{
      id: 1,
      name: "Paris",
      value: 99,
      parents: [{
        id: 8,
        name: null,
        value: 200,
        parents: [{ id: 23, name: "Crockford", value: 86, parents: [] }]
       }, {
        id: 42,
        name: "Nibbler",
        value: 123,
        parents: []
      }]
    }]
  } 
}
```